# How to find the equation of common chord between a circle and a parabola?

Tags: vector-spaces, circles, conic-sections, parametric

> Question:  Let $S_1$ be the focus of the parabola $$y^2 = 8x$$ and $PQ$ be the common chord of the circle $x^2 + y^ 2-2x-4y= 0$ and the given parabola. The area of the triangle PQS is?

I circumvented this problem knowing that the circle touches the origin as it has no constant value and so does the standard parabola. I assumed (accidentally and also correctly) that the chord was the diameter, knowing the centre was $(1,2)$ and I found the other vertex as $(2,4)$ and solved the question getting the correct answer.

Is there perhaps a generalised method to find the equation of the parabola and the circle? I know that the chord of a parabola is given by the formula $y(t_1+1_2)=2at_1t_1$, but I haven't figured how to use it to find actual equations of chord apart the formula

Comment: We just need to find the two intersection points of the parabola and the circle, by solving $y^2 = 8x$ and $x^2 + y^2 - 2x - 4y=0$.

Comment: @player3236 you are right but i tried substituting $y^2$ that and I got an equation with both $x$ and $y$

Comment: Use $x = y^2/8$ instead.

Comment: @player3236 Thanks you are right, that could work but it would be a biquadratic equation. Is there any way to manipulate the equation I put in the question?

Comment: We can factorize it.

Answer (score 1):

To find the common chord of the parabola and the circle, we must solve their equations simultaneously. Substituting $x = \frac{y^2}{8}$ in the equation for the circle:
$$ \frac{y^4}{64} + y^2- 2\frac{y^2}{8} - 4y = 0 \qquad \implies \qquad y^4 + 48y^2 - 256y = 0$$
$\therefore$ Either $y = 0, \implies x = 0,$ or $y^3 -48y -256 = 0.$ By rational root theorem, $y=4$ satisfies the cubic equation. $y = 4 \implies x = 2$. Thus $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$ are the points of intersection.
Let $P = (0,0)$ and $Q = (2,4)$. We know that $S_1 = (2,0)$. Now we can use Heron's formula to calculate the area.